# SQLXML Bulk Load connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, sqlxml, bulk-load

I use SQLXML Bulk Load to import data from xml to DB. With MS Sql Server 2008 works great.

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4 objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4();
            objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=server;database=databaseName;integrated security=SSPI";
            objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.xml";
            objBL.KeepIdentity = false;
            objBL.Execute ("schema.xml","data.xml");
```

Then I create MS SQL Compact CE 3.5 database - `tempDb.sdf` and try to connect to this DB

```
objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; database = D:\\project\\xmlread\\xmlread\\bin\\Debug\\tempDb.sdf;integrated security=SSPI";
```

But have - Invalid connection string. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first in connection string using `data source` and `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0`, so connection string work -

```
objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0; 
data source = D:\\project\\xmlread\\xmlread\\bin\\Debug\\tempDb.sdf;";
```

But then i see this message (on execute method) -

> Bulkload will only work with SQL Server 2000 or later.

So I think that SQLXML 4.0 not supported ms sql compact ce